# "ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic is not supported" while installing Virtualbox on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, virtualbox

I am getting this error while installing Virtualbox on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

```
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-34-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-34-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have the -proposed repository enabled. Bad Idea.

```
$ rmadison linux-image-generic | grep groovy
[...]
 linux-image-generic | 5.8.0.33.38          | groovy-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
 linux-image-generic | 5.8.0.33.38          | groovy-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
 linux-image-generic | 5.8.0.34.39          | groovy-proposed  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
```

Your question states that you are using kernel version 5.8.0.34. You can see that version is ONLY available (as of today) in the groovy-proposed repository.

- The -proposed pocket of the Ubuntu repositories is for testing packages before release into -updates. In a few days or weeks, the package will migrate to -updates...or might be withdrawn if it fails testing.
- **Advice**: As a new user, DON'T use -proposed. It's likely to cause breakage exactly like you encountered.

---

How to fix the problem:

First, stop using the -proposed source.

Second, wait a few days or weeks for the -proposed packages *already on your system* to be properly integrated with your system (that's one reason they are in -proposed!). Then dkms will automagically work, and the install will work properly.

Alternately, folks who have proper skills can downgrade their packages. That's not a trivial operation for a beginner, and it risks various forms of breakage, so I'm not going to explain that in detail.

Comment: Thank you!! Understood and I will wait for few days until there is upgrade. Right now in software and update I see that the proposed is unchecked already. So I believe I do not have to do anything else here, right? And thanks again!!

Comment: @tonjo - this answer applied for only a few days (the time a package is in -proposed). Kernel 5.8.0-34 has already been superseded by 5.8.0-36, so it seems likely you have a different problem and this answer won't help you.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, solved reinstalling.

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar looking problem after doing a system update today. I removed virtualbox

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then installed virtualbox from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
which now works. See also https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=99564

Comment: Nice that it is resolved for you. :) You may want to keep the "proposed" option off in developer option in software update. One experience user advised me this thing to run in to similar problems in future. You can see this in one of the answers in this question.

Comment: Kernel 5.8.0-36-generic is now in the official repositories, and unfortunately this error with virtualbox is still there. Installing the downloaded `*.deb` file (https://www.virtualbox.org) using `gdebi` worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade Linux kernel to version 5.8.0-33 to fix this problem.

First, remove virtualbox and virtualbox-dkms.

```
sudo apt remove virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
```

Secondly, remove linux kernel 5.8.0-34

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-5.8.0-34-generic linux-moudules-5.8.0-34-generic linux-modules-5.8.0-34-generic
```

Thirdly install linux-kernel 5.8.0-33

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge
```

Finally **do not forget** to update your grub settings:

```
sudo update-grub
```

then reboot, and install Virtualbox again

```
sudo apt install virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
```

If you see `Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module`,
you need remove all packages related to virtualbox. Then go to [Linux_Downloads - Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) to download Virtualbox 6.1.16 and install.

Comment: Hi!! I tried to do this but on the second command I get the following error message:  https://i.postimg.cc/TYZGDw4r/Screenshot-from-2021-01-04-16-59-30.png

Comment: Now when I run sudo apt upgrade the following error comes: https://i.postimg.cc/zvQRRc3D/Screenshot-from-2021-01-04-18-51-02.png

Comment: You need remove all virtualbox package, including virtualbox-dkms and virtualbox-qt, and download virtualbox 6.1 [link]https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.16-140961~Ubuntu~eoan_amd64.deb and use dpkg install

Comment: After some trial and error, I have succeeded in completely removing the virtualbox and reinstalling it from Oracle repository. It resolved the problem. Now I have another issue which I am posting in my new question. Thank you!