# Anyone else having trouble with virtualbox shared folders permissions all of a sudden?

Tags: kernel, permissions, virtualbox

Ubuntu 20.04 MATE - host
Ubuntu 20.04 Metacity - Guest
Ubuntu 20.04 MATE - Guest

I don't know which parts are relevant... But my metacity guest locked up... for whatever reason, memory was at 98% or so when the screen froze. I restarted that guest. It returned normally, But my shared folders are all owned by root now, instead of my user, so EVERYTHING on the share is read-only. The host hasn't changed.

I noticed that there is a kernel error scrolling VMMDev: Guest Log: `vbg_status_code_to_errno: Unhandled err -78` every 4 seconds. I noticed it started happening right when I started playing with the Shared Folders options on the VM VirtualBox Manager... But it didn't stop when I set things back to their original state, so it just may have been timing... again, "dont know what parts are relevant"...

That message seemed to be kernel related, so I contemplated reinstalling the kernel....
which currently is `linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic`
The current files in my /usr/src are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jan  5 13:54 linux-headers-5.4.0-59/
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jan  5 13:54 linux-headers-5.4.0-59-generic/
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jan  7 06:51 linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-34/
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jan  7 06:51 linux-headers-5.8.0-34-generic/
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jan 10 06:07 linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-36/
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Jan 10 06:07 ./
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jan 10 06:07 linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic/
```

Instead of reinstalling, I rebooted into 5.8.0-34-generic.... The problem exists there too.

So I went back to 5.4.0-59-generic and the problem is **NOT** there.

The problem is **NOT** on my MATE guest either. That guest is currently on 5.4.0-60-generic.

According to `last reboot`, unless someone sees something different, it seems the problem didn't start until i came back into the newest kernel???

```
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-59-generic Sun Jan 10 19:29   still running
reboot   system boot  5.8.0-34-generic Sun Jan 10 19:27 - 19:29  (00:02)
reboot   system boot  5.8.0-36-generic Sun Jan 10 19:26 - 19:26  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  5.8.0-36-generic Sun Jan 10 18:42 - 19:25  (00:43)
reboot   system boot  5.8.0-36-generic Sun Jan 10 17:42 - 18:42  (00:59)
reboot   system boot  5.8.0-36-generic Sun Jan 10 13:34 - 17:41  (04:07)
reboot   system boot  5.8.0-36-generic Sun Jan 10 12:42 - 17:39  (04:57)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-59-generic Tue Jan  5 10:05 - 17:39 (5+07:33)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-58-generic Mon Jan  4 12:15 - 14:11 (1+01:56)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-58-generic Mon Jan  4 00:32 - 16:16  (15:43)
```

I don't do any special installs or anything. Is 5.8X supposed to be installed instead of 5.4.0.60??? Or is that irrelevant and there is another problem that jumps out?

**Update:**

At the advice of the comments I just decided to put a hold on the 5.4*** kernel and just kept using that one just fine, until I was ready to upgrade...
On 1/19/21 I noticed that Virtualbox 6.1.16 came down the pipe in the ubuntu repository... I upgraded from there, and I am having the same issue with the 5.8**** kernels. My problem seems a bit different from the 3 or 4 similar issues that I read about... I don't know if a manual install going to make the difference or if I am possibly experiencing a different bug... Again, my system actually runs as normal as it always has, except for this one issue.

Comment: Did you install virtual box from the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: @PJSingh ....honestly, I don't even remember, that was over a year ago... But I am going to say yes because I probably went the easy route. `apt-list --installed` shows it, so I am assuming it would not be on that list unless I used the repository... what did you have in mind?

Comment: What version of Virtualbox are you running?  Help -> About should tell you.  6.1.10 has a bug with kernel 5.8 and does not work properly.  6.1.16 that is the current version from Virtualbox themselves works just fine with the 5.8 kernel.

Comment: @Terrance I literally JUST NOW, saw another somewhat similar question that had links with you talking about this... I was gonna ask you if you thought this was related, because my guest actually starts and functions nicely, except for the shared folders... but yes I'm on 6.1.10. You think it's worth it to upgrade my working host? or just wait until the bug is fixed... the problem is on my junk guest, the important guest(MATE) went to 5.4.0-60, not 5.8XX... so I don't have an "urgency" to fix this one(metacity), I just worry about the future kernels of the MATE guest.

Comment: I stopped quite awhile ago using the Virtualbox from the Ubuntu Repos and started using the one from Virtualbox themselves.  They have a repo you can setup and it keeps it updated just fine.  I actually learned of the bugs here from users that installed from the Ubuntu repos as mine worked fine when my system updated to 5.8.  So, yeah, I do recommend going with the Virtualbox 6.1.16 version.  I guess if you wanted to remove the HWE kernels for now that would get rid of the 5.8, then the Ubuntu repo version would continue to work fine.

Comment: @Terrance yeah i guess both of those are actually good options... I actually didn't know Virtualbox had a repo, i'm somewhat interested in that... but I am kinda lazy right now, so it's good to know I can just use the current version. Not knowing much about kernels, why did I end up with an HWE kernel? that is not something I did specifically, it came down the pipe with upgrades... but only on this one guest. I was actually worried for a minute about rebooting the others, but they got the normal kernels. Could that be the actual mistake(bug)?

Comment: Not sure how the HWE was installed.  You can look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack also check the policy on it `apt-cache policy linux-generic-hwe-20.04`.  It could have been installed with another package, or it could have come down with the normal upgrades.  I did notice recently my NVIDIA graphics driver automatically upgrade from `nvidia-driver-455` to `nvidia-driver-460`.  Normally I would have to specify the jump like that.

Comment: I think you are running into the kernel issue. Uninstall virtualbox and download the *.deb file from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads (See https://askubuntu.com/a/1305552/100356).

Comment: yeah I think that is most likely correct.... I'm probably going to opt to remove the HWE or wait for a fix.... Thanks for the info @Terrance and Pjsingh

Comment: @WU-TANG For what it's worth, even if you downloaded a `.deb` file and manually installed it using `apt`, it would show up in the list of installed packages.  Not relevant to your problem (sorry!), but just something I've noticed and in response to your earlier comment in this discussion.  Good luck with your problem!

Comment: @Terrance A little disheartening... 6.1.16 has come down the pipe in the ubuntu repository... and I now have it installed. I am still seeing the same problem. I even reinstalled everything that is installed that matched the wildcard *5.8.0-38*.... I am curious now, (since my problem seems a bit different from everyone else's that I read about) Do you have shared folders on your guest and are they properly owned by the user, or by root?.... I am wondering if I am experiencing a different bug...

Comment: @WU-TANG I will have to take a look and see.

Comment: @WU-TANG Maybe you need to update the Guest Additions to the guest host?  I just removed the VirtualBox version and installed the Ubuntu Repo version.  Both worked the same for me.  Both show pretty much the same version:  Virtualbox Repo ver `6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.12.8)` and Ubuntu Repo ver `6.1.16_Ubuntu r140961 (Qt5.12.8)`.  That's all I can think is the Guest Additions maybe.

Comment: However, with the Virtualbox version I don't see errors like `Qt WARNING: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 17254, resource id: 6336469, major code: 40 (TranslateCoords), minor code: 0` but that didn't seem to cause any failures in the Ubuntu repository version.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks for all the feedback.... that actually did it... I had to boot into 5.8.0-38 and reinstall the guest additions... If you to post that, we can use that as an answer.... Thanks. Now I'm curious if it would have worked on 6.1.10, but unwilling to experiment, lol... Every other guest I'm running is running MATE so I don't see the problem anywhere else to test. Thanks again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When upgrading Virtualbox from version 6.1.10 to 6.1.16 make sure to also go into your VMs and load up the Guest Additions CD through *Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD*

Then in a terminal window in your guest run:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

*Mainly running the above line to make sure all build apps are installed, like gcc, make, etc.*

Then install the Guest Additions to help with folder sharing, shared clipboard, drag and drop, etc.

```
sudo /media/$USER/VBox_GAs_6.1.16/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Comment: Thanks again.... also worth mentioning: Specifically re-installing them in the booted 5.8XXX kernel... At first I re-installed them in the 5.4XXXX kernel, but it had no effect on 5.8XXX... I can see this sequence happening to someone else if they are, for the first time, pulling down 5.8XXX in an update and deciding to update guest additions before the reboot.